# Preventing Stanford Core NLP Server from outputting the text it receives

Tags: nlp, stanford-nlp

I am running a [Stanford CoreNLP](http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/) server:

```
java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9001 -timeout 50000
```

Whenever it receives some text, it outputs it in the shell it is running it. How to prevent this from happening?

---

It that matters, here is the code I use to pass data to Stanford Core NLP Server:

```
'''
From https://github.com/smilli/py-corenlp/blob/master/example.py
'''
from pycorenlp import StanfordCoreNLP
import pprint

if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000')
    fp = open("long_text.txt")
    text = fp.read()
    output = nlp.annotate(text, properties={
        'annotators': 'tokenize,ssplit,pos,depparse,parse',
        'outputFormat': 'json'
    })
    pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)
    pp.pprint(output)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's currently not a way to do this, but you're the second person that's asked. So, it's now in the Github code, and will make it into the next release. For the future, you should be able to set the `-quiet` flag, and the server will not write to standard out.

Comment: Has this feature to turn off verbose output been added for the Python interface as of Jun 2020?

Comment: @jackson95 which Python interface are you referring to?

Comment: stanfordnlp (or spacy which is newer)?

Answer (score 1):

I asked the [same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37483608/stanford-corenlp-server-disable-logging) and can offer some kind of workaround. I am running the server at the moment in a virtual machine. In order to prevent the logging output for now I run it with `2&>1 >/dev/null` pipe arguments:

```
java -mx6g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -prettyPrint false 2&>1 >/dev/null
```

This gives a considerable performance boost until we wait for `3.6.1`.

Comment: I added '-quiet' to the command line, and it seems to work, though processing a lot of rows still takes some time

Answer (score 1):

When using the [Stanford CoreNLP Client from the Python `stanza` library](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/corenlp_client.html)¹, you can pass the [`be_quiet`](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/client_properties.html#corenlp-server-start-options-server) option to turn of logging from the server.

```py
nlp = StanfordCoreNLP('http://localhost:9000', be_quiet=True)
```

---

¹ Which the original question isn't, but a future visitor to this question might be.